# Data won't be load in div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in one of my ASP.NET MVC views.

When the page is loaded, I Render an `PartialView` inside a `div`.

```
<div id="#jobs">
   @{
      Html.RenderAction("Jobs", "Home", new { enviroment = "value" });
   }
</div>
```

My action `Jobs`, looks like that (It's very simple):

```
public ActionResult Jobs(string enviroment)
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    model.Jobs = //Get Jobs...
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

My Partial View just contains a table with all `Jobs`.

Then I have a HTML.DropDownList, wich contains my enviroments. 
When this DropDownList changes it fires a JavaScipt function wich should update my Table inside my `Jobs div`.

The function looks like that:

```
function updateJobs() {
    var selectedEnviroment = $("#enviromentsDropdown").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("Jobs", "Home")',
        data: {'enviroment': selectedEnviroment},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#jobs").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The function is working perfectly and `data` contains everything I want to have, but it's not updating my `Jobs <div>`.

If I instead put my data in another `div` it works without any problems.

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong and why it doesn't want to update my `Jobs div`?

Comment: `<div id="#jobs">` should be `<div id="jobs">` as the answer shows. This is a typo question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `<div id="#jobs">` to `<div id="jobs">`

Comment: Well spotted, I missed that. :)

Comment: Haha nice one I missed that totally! 
Thank you :)